# Iphone SDK for Tiger MAC

Tags: ios, iphone, osx-tiger

I am running Mac Tiger on my VMware, trying to install iphone SDK and Xcode, and then I found out I have to have leopard in order to be able to develop for Iphone.  I was wondering is there any Iphone SDK and Xcode for MAc Tiger 10.4 ??? many thanks

Comment: Also, you need an Intel-based Mac.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apple stopped supporting Mac OS 10.4 quite a long time ago. In fact, new iPhone 3.2 SDK is available only for Mac OS 10.6. So you'd either have to get a newer version of the system, or search for older SDK over the Internet (some third party sites can still host it).

The 10.5.x version is still available on Apple's developer connection, however it's SDK 3.1.3 only.

Hope this was helpful, Paul